# Replace a variable string with empty string

Tags: c#, string

I have an xml file that I am using linq-to-XML to read.  Linq-to-XML is preserving the line breaks and spaces for indenting.

So instead of having a guid like this:

```
"FB5417E2-DB15-481d-80D6-D0C4CB26EB1F"
```

I am getting stuff like this:

```
"\n    FB5417E2-DB15-481d-80D6-D0C4CB26EB1F"
```

I have made this method to try and help compensate for this:

```
public static string ValueTrimmed(this XElement element)
{         
    if (element != null)
        // Remove the newlines and spaces
        return element.Value.Replace("\n      ", "");

    return "";
}
```

The problem is that this only works for "\n" + 6 spaces.

Is there a way to remove "\n" + Any number of spaces?

Note: I have some scenarios where the "\n" + x spaces is on the inside of the value.
For example:

```
TextTextTextTextTextTextText\n     TextTextTextTextTextTextText
```

Comment: Are there *any* spaces that need to be preserved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove all newlines followed by spaces:

```
return Regex.Replace(element.Value, @"\n\s*", String.Empty);
```

If you want to preserve a single space between lines:

```
return Regex.Replace(element.Value, @"\n\s*", " ").Trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [`string.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) to remove all leading and trailing whitespace:

```
return element.Value.Trim();
```

Comment: That would work for the example I showed, but I have text that has wrapped across several lines (ie `TextTextText\n    texttexttext`)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of fiddling around with regular expressions, specify whether white-space is preserved or not when you create your `XDocument` using the appropriate `LoadOptions`:

**Preserve white-space:**

```
var xdoc1 = XDocument.Parse("<root>\r\n</root>", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
var xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(@"\path\to\xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

**Ignore white-space:**

```
var xdoc1 = XDocument.Parse("<root>\r\n</root>", LoadOptions.None);
var xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(@"\path\to\xml", LoadOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = input
    .Replace("\\n", String.Empty) // replace escaped \n with nothing
    .Trim(); // removing leading (and trailing) spaces
```

or (try, not sure)

```
string result = input.Trim(new[] { '\n' });
```

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereIf were you, inside the outer if place another if checking for "\n" and if that returns true then in a loop check for "\" or "n" or " " and replace with "".

Essentially something like this in pseudo-code...

```
if (string != null) //check if string is not null
{
    if ((string.indexOf(0) == "\\") && (string.indexOf(1) == "n")) //check if string begins with \n
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) \\since string begins with "\n" iterate until each character is neither "\", "n", " " and replace each one of those with ""
        {
            if((string.indexOf(i) == "\\") || (string.indexOf(i) == "n") || (string.indexOf(i) == " "))
                string.indexOf(i) = "";
        }

    }
}
```

excuse me, that might be a little messy and some of the syntax may be slightly off, but you get the jist.